# Deleting a record in a rad grid

Tags: c#, radgrid, radgridview

I am trying to delete a record from a rad grid which is bounded using a view of two tables (one parent table and another child table). I would like to delete a record from child table.

Could you please suggest how i can pass a value from front end page to code behind page.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/deleting-child-grids-in-a-nested-radgrid